# How do I get a custom script to run when using hook_cron in my custom module?

Tags: 7, cron

I am brand new to module development, fresh off the D7 tutorial boat. What I want to do cannot be that hard.

I have created my first module called get_weather, with get_weather.info and get_weather.module properly installed and drupal recognized.

I created another simple script that has one function, which I want to run when cron runs. 'update_weather' the ONLY thing this does is return the temperature for that time and store it in the database.

There is nothing to display, there are no blocks to render. However, this does not work:

```
function get_weather_cron() { update_weather(); }
```

What's going on here? I get no errors, but nothing happens at all? How do I get my module to run my custom function when cron runs?

Note that my custom function works fine if I run it from a script outside of a Drupal module environment.

Here is code based on comments feedback:

```
include('weather.php');
function get_weather_cron(){
    watchdog('get_weather_debug', 'Cron function triggered');
    update_weather();
}
```

Also here is update_weather, which is included in the weather.php include file:

```
function update_weather() {
    $page['weather'] = scrape_weather();
    //insert into db code here;
}
```

Again, when I simply run this php normally outside of the drupal enviroment, everything works fine. All I want to do is run this same script when cron runs so this is done automatically. No function in my entire library for this functionality has anything to do with Drupal. I am simply trying to activate it by using cron.

Comment: Did you clear the caches since implementing `hook_cron()`?

Comment: yea, several times. One thing I am confused about in learning about modules - I have to define the function - function get_weather_cron(){}. Well, in normal php that is just a definition. Don't I have to call it? I did put get_weather_cron() right after the definition, but still nothing. thoughts? thanks!

Comment: The hook_cron() will be automatically called by Drupal, so the answer to your question is - no, you don't have to call it directly yourself. Try adding the following code to the get_weather_cron() function: watchdog('get_weather_debug', 'Cron function triggered'); After that, clean cache, run the cron manually and then go to the log to see if the "Cron function triggered" message is saved there.

Comment: Also make doubly sure that your module is installed and enabled

Comment: brand new ? lol ! you made my day ! Ok .. To debug I would check these 1) Is Cron set up properly, verify using elysia cron statistics 2) Log a dummy watchdog entry for cron invoked i.e first line in `hook_cron()`

Comment: glad to be of comic assistance :). Ok, as Ivan suggested, I copied and pasted that into the body of my get_weather_cron function. As kantu suggested, it is the first line in the function. Clive, removed the module, it disappeared from module list - add it back and there it was again. It is now checked and installed. Ivan, after doing all that and following your instructions, the only thing I get is that "cron run completed."

Comment: try to call [module_implements('cron')](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_implements/7) in devel/php - it should return your module. does it ?

Comment: I hope you didn't define the hook as `get_weather_cron() { update_weather(); }` because that is not how you define a hook.

Comment: Can you post your exact code?

Comment: Adding to googletorp comment, show also `update_weather()` code.

Comment: @kiamlaluno that's exactly what I did per the instructions here http://drupal.org/node/1095546, "To implement any hook in Drupal, replace "hook" in the hook name with your module's short name, and create a function in the .module file with that name". I wanted to avoid posting code since it was so long, but ok, let me see what I can do.

Comment: A hook is still a function, and you are not defining a function with `get_weather_cron() { update_weather(); }`. That is why @googletorp asked you to post the exact code you are using; if you don't show the exact code you are using, for both the hook and the other function, users cannot answer your question, which is about code you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to drupal! One of the first things that will learn is that Drupal keeps an internal cache of *all* hooks implemented on the site. Just because you implement [hook_cron()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) in your custom module, and then run cron, does not mean it will work.

Steps I would suggest to help fix

1. Install [drush](https://drupal.org/project/drush) (this is Drupal's Swiss Army knife)
2. run `drush cc all`
3. run `drush cron`

Hopefully it will all be resolved

To check if your module is installed and enabled correctly you can

- `drush pml | grep get_weather` (or alternatively look at the modules list in the UI)

Or to check if there is something wrong with your function `update_weather();`, you can run it in the context of drupal (i.e. alter a full drupal bootstrap with all modules loaded)

- `drush php-eval "print update_weather();"` - you can also place additional logging or printing in your function to see what is going on.

Of course, don't forget to define all you functions that you want to execute in the .module file, as every enabled module, has it's .module file included on every request. On a side note, why don't you do away with calling another function from hook cron?

```
function get_weather_cron() { update_weather(); }
```

Simply use something similar to the following one.

```
function get_weather_cron() {
  // more actual weather getting code here
  variable_set('get_weather_temp', 23);
}
```

It should be easier to read for the next person too.